# How to correctly dispose a client stream if the connection has disconnected?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-signalr, system.threading.channels

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 2.1 v1.0.4 and have a ChannelReader stream being consumed by a typescript client using v1.0.4.

The channel surfaces event data specific to a single entity, so it's expected the client would subscribe to a channel when the user of the client navigates to a page rendering data for that single entity.  If the user navigates to the same page but for a different entity then the client would make another subscribe call.

Now the questions I have are about how best to unsubscribe the stream, and also in general, what the lifetime of the stream is to the client under hub connection stop/start scenarios, and if the server explicitly aborts a connection (due to access_token timeouts and so to trigger the client to refresh their connection)?

There doesn't appear to be some connection state surfaced from the api so I currently use an RxJs Subject to surface some connection state to my UI components/services, i.e. when the hub connection's start call is successful I surface "true", and when the onclose callback is called I surface "false".  This allows me to attempt to call dispose on a previously subscribed stream to clean things up during a connection disconnect/stop, and then if necessary call subscribe to the stream again on a successful start call.

I have tried calling dispose on a stream which is fine if the hub is connected, but it errors if the connection is in a disconnected state.  I'm wondering if this is a bug or not.  Should I be able to dispose a stream even when the hub is disconnected?

Is it okay to just do a `delete streamsubscription` and then recreate as required, or will this leak in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what the lifetime of the stream is to the client under hub connection stop/start scenarios, and if the server explicitly aborts a connection (due to access_token timeouts and so to trigger the client to refresh their connection).

When the connection is terminated (either because of `stop` being called on the client or the server aborting the connection) the `error` method of your subscriber will be called with an error indicating the stream has been terminated because the connection was terminated. In general, you should handle the `error` method and consider it a terminal event (i.e. the stream will never yield additional objects). On the server, the `Context.ConnectionAborted` token will be triggered if the connection is terminated (by either side) and you can stop writing to your stream.

If you're already using RxJS, I'd highly recommend building a small wrapper to convert the object you get back from SignalR into a proper RxJS `Observable`. The object we return is not *actually* an `Observable`, but it has all the same basic methods (a `subscribe` method that takes an object with `complete`, `next` and `error` methods), so it should be trivial to wrap it.

> I have tried calling dispose on a stream which is fine if the hub is connected, but it errors if the connection is in a disconnected state. I'm wondering if this is a bug or not.

Yeah, that's probably a bug. We shouldn't throw if you dispose after a hub is disconnected. Can you file that on https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR ? To work around it you can fairly safely just `try...catch` the error and suppress it (or maybe log it if you're paranoid).

> Is it okay to just do a delete streamsubscription and then recreate as required, or will this leak in any way?

You should **always** `dispose` the subscription. If you just `delete` it, then we have no way to know that you're done with it and we never tell the server to stop. If you call `dispose` (and are connected) we send a message to the server "cancelling" the stream. In ASP.NET Core 2.1 we don't expose this cancellation to you, but we do stop reading from the `ChannelReader`. In ASP.NET Core 2.2 we allow you to accept a `CancellationToken` in your Hub method and the `dispose` method on the client will trigger this token in the Hub method. I'd highly recommend you try the latest preview of ASP.NET Core 2.2 and use a `CancellationToken` in your Hub method to stop the stream:

```
public ChannelReader<object> MyStreamingMethod(..., CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    // pass 'cancellationToken' over to whatever process is writing to the channel
    // and stop writing when the token is triggered
}
```

Note: If you do this, you don't need to monitor `Context.ConnectionAborted`, the token passed in to your Hub method will cover all cancellation cases.

On a related note, you should **always** use `Channel.CreateBounded<T>(size)` to create your channel. If you use an unbounded channel it's much easier to leak memory since the writer can just keep writing indefinitely. If you use a bounded channel, the writer will be stopped (`WriteAsync` and `WaitToWriteAsync` will "block") if there are `size` un-read items in the channel (because, for example, the client has disconnected and we've stopped reading).

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  Very informative.  I have been wrapping the dispose in a try/catch as you suggested.  I shall make the change to use observable.create today and also see if I still get the dispose exception.  If I do I'll raise an issue in github.